# what does the phrase "singular intellect" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-meaning

I have heard of staggering intellect but does singular intellect mean the same? Which phrase should be used in what context?

Comment: Have you looked up possible meanings of *singular*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/singular, singular as an adjective can be defined as "distinguished by superiority" or "being out of the ordinary." Therefore, when singular is used to modify the word intellect, it means superior/extraordinary intellect. According to http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/staggering, a synonym for staggering is extraordinary. Therefore, these two things mean similar things as they both refer to a high intellectual level.

Answer (score 1):

*Singular* here means *unique*, although it's not usually meant to be taken literally.  A person of singular intellect might not be uniquely intelligent, but at least unusually or notably so.